# ¿Como ocultar un div al mostrar otro?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Hola buenas soy novato y estoy perdidisimo con esto. Necesito que cuando hago onclick para mostrar el "precio2" se me oculte a su vez el #precio1. Me funciona el accionador para mostrar el "precio2" pero no consigo que esto haga que se oculte el "precio1", creo que estoy usando mal el hide y show. Seguro que hay varias formas de hacerlo sencillo y en una sola función, espero que podáis ayudarme. Gracias!

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 function show(bloq) {
  obj = document.getElementById(bloq);
  obj.style.display = (obj.style.display=='none') ? 'block' : 'none';
}

</script>

<script>
 if ($('#precio2').is(':show'))
 $('#precio1').show();
 else
 $('#precio1').hide();

</script>
```

```html
<div class="show" id="precio1"><p>100€</p></div>
<div style="display:none;" id="precio2"><p>200€</p></div>
      
<div><a onclick="show('precio2')"> Accionador</a></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Podrias hacer uso del [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) de jquery para ocultar o mostrar un `div`u otro.

Ademas si vas a adjuntar un evento es mejor si lo haces de la misma forma, por eso use el `click` de jquery en lugar de onclick en el html.

Recuerda agregar la libreria de jquery en tu codigo

```js
$("#accionar").click(function(){
  
  $('#precio1').toggle();
  $('#precio2').toggle();   
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="show" id="precio1"><p>100€</p></div>
<div style="display:none;" id="precio2"><p>200€</p></div>
      
<div><a id="accionar"> Accionador</a></div>
```

Comment: He probado ambas opciones copiando tal cual y en los dos casos consigo mostrar el precio 2 pero esto no hace ocultarse el precio 1. ¿Porque puede ser?

Comment: si habilitas el developer tools del browser, al cual accedes con F12, puedes ver en la solapa Console si hay algun error de javascript ? la verdad es raro que no funcione ya que la implementacion que puse la puedes probar desde aqui mismo y esta respondiendo. Recordaste agregar la libreria jquery ?

Comment: Es verdad! El codigo funciona, he creado un archivo y hace justo lo que quiero, sin embargo cuando lo integro en mi pagina no. Voy a revisar. Gracias!

Comment: Increible! el error viene del archivo "bootstrap.min.css", si elimino este enlace del archivo funciona. Pero... claro, no puedo eliminar a este archivo completo, se te ocurre de donde puede venir el error o si hay alguna forma de solucionarlo? Estoy trabajando con la versión 3.3.6 de bootstrap.

Comment: que dice el mensaje de error ? en que parte del html lo marca. Incluiste el .js de bootstrap?

Comment: En la consola me da 3 errores, si tengo el js de bootstrap. Uncaught TypeError: $(...).ready(...) is not a function
jcf.js:9 Calling CSSStyleSheet.insertRule() with one argument is deprecated. Please pass the index argument as well: insertRule(x, 0). Haciendo referencia a setting.js. El segundo: Uncaught ReferenceError: WOW is not defined haciendo referencia a custom.js y el tercero: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined. tambien en custom.js .  Perdona el caso de mensaje pero no me deja hacer salto de linea sin enviar.

Comment: Si en tu codigo defines ese .ready reemplazalo por $(function() { ... }); es el equivalente. Aqui https://api.jquery.com/ready/ lo explica

Comment: Buff he intentado hacer lo que dices pero no consigo saber a que te re refieres. ¿Donde exactamente debo cambiar el ready por function?

Comment: Alli mismo en el ready en javascript. Donde usas el ready lo quitas y solo dejas $(function() {. Analizaste el link donde explica el uso del ready en jquery alli explica sobre el tema

Answer (score 2):

Excelente día, después de varios días o semanas le pregunté a mi maestro de programación cómo podía hacer que al tener varios botones ejecutara el mismo script en una sola hoja la misma función de ocultar divs y apareciera el div respectivo a su botón, pues está más fácil de lo que pensaba, haciendo un switch statement. 
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp
Básicamente es lo siguiente.

```
switch(expression) {
case n:
    code block
    break;
case n:
    code block
    break;
default:
        code block
}
```

Entonces lo que hice fué esto:

```
function myFunction(idButton) {
  var producto1 = document.getElementById('producto1');
  var producto2 = document.getElementById('producto2');
  var producto3 = document.getElementById('producto3');



 switch(idButton) {
 case 1:

          producto1.style.display = 'block';
          producto2.style.display = 'none';
          producto3.style.display = 'none';
    break;

 case 2:
          producto1.style.display = 'none';
          producto2.style.display = 'block';
          producto3.style.display = 'none';
    break;

 case 3:
          producto1.style.display = 'none';
          producto2.style.display = 'none';
          producto3.style.display = 'block';
    break;

default:
          alert("hay un problema: No existe el producto.")
        }

   }
```

Donde el número que contiene "case" es el id que se le asigna al botón onclick en html.

```
<li onclick="myFunction(1)">Producto1</li>
<li onclick="myFunction(2)">Producto2</li>
<li onclick="myFunction(3)">Producto3</li>
```

los de aquí arriba serían los botones yo quice hacerlo con li

```
<div id="producto1" style="display:none;">
   <div class="tituloDiv">
      <h3>Producto1</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="contenidoDiv">
      <p>Descripción producto1.</p>
   </div>
</div>

<div id="producto2" style="display:none;">
     <div class="tituloDiv">
        <h3>Producto1</h3>
     </div>
     <div class="contenidoDiv">
        <p>Descripción producto2.</p>
     </div>
</div>

<div id="producto3" style="display:none;">
    <div class="tituloDiv">
         <h3>Producto1</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="contenidoDiv">
        <p>Descripción producto3.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Saludos c:

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear una función para cambiar el estado de los div:

```js
function cambiaVisibilidad() {
       var div1 = document.getElementById('precio1');
       var div2 = document.getElementById('precio2');
       if(div2.style.display == 'block'){
           div2.style.display = 'none';
           div1.style.display = 'block';
       }else{
          div2.style.display = 'block';
          div1.style.display = 'none';
         }
   }
```

```html
  <html>

<body>

 <div class="show" id="precio1"><p>100€</p></div>
 <div style="display:none;" id="precio2"><p>200€</p></div>
 <div onclick="cambiaVisibilidad()"><a id="accionar">Accionador</a>                 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola Elenasys,  gracias por tu respuesta. La he probado y consigo mostrar el precio 2 pero sin ocultar el precio 1...¿porque puede ser?

Comment: hola Diego, que raro, si ejecutas el botón "Ejecutar Fragmento de código" no funciona? :0 yo lo ve funcionando!

Comment: Si, si. Funciona perfecto perdona. Es cuando lo inserto en mi página cuando deja de funcionar, no tengo ni idea de porque. Tendre algun error o algo que le pueda estar afectando, voy a revisarlo. Muchas gracias!

Comment: jeje, ok Diego.